# How to use field value of one object in another using self.pool.get in openerp?

Tags: openerp-7

This is my code in .py file.I want to fetch value of field list_price in product.product and use it in my custom module which inherits sale.order.
Can i store the value of list_price field in my custom field i.e qty_available?
When i print value of wg_qty_avail it shows None even list_price is having value 2000

class practice(osv.osv):

```
_inherit = 'sale.order'
_columns = {
    'qty_available': fields.float('Quantity'),
}
```

def get_val(self, cr, uid, id, product, context=None):

```
    result={}
    wg_qty_avail = self.pool.get('product.product').browse(cr, uid,product,context=context).list_price
    print "---------------------------", wg_qty_avail
    result['qty_available'] = wg_qty_avail
```

practice()

xml file is ok..it calls the method get_val by a button click.

Please help.Where am i wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning the value to 'qty_available' field correctly

Remove  result['qty_available'] = wg_qty_avail

```
return  {'value': {'qty_available':wg_qty_avail}}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: good to know that.... u can spare few moments to rate this answer... It would help me in future...

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to vote up ur ans..bcoz i am new..so sorry..can u rate the ques if u can..Thank You..